# Debug jQuery/angular event handlers in Chrome Tools (getEventListeners)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

We can use Chrome Tools to inspect event listeners attached to specific DOM nodes. If we attach an event listener with JavaScript we will see the attach point in the output:

```
2277 document.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```
> getEventListeners(document)
< Objectclick: Array[1]
    0: Object
        listener: (e)
        ...
        [[FunctionLocation]]: exact_line.js:2277
        ...
```

However, when we use Angular (jQuery) event binding, such as `on` and `off` we lose the bind location (it appears to get lost in the jQuery/jqLite call). How can we backtrack the actual binding location?

```
2277 $document.on("click", click);
```

```
> getEventListeners(document)
< Objectclick: Array[1]
    0: Object
        listener: (a)
        ...
        [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3 (no idea)
        ...
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have encountered the same issue :)

Comment: @Pirozek, Unfortunately, no. At this point I just try to be very careful when adding event listeners and having a general idea of where the events are coming from. It is not ideal.